# .net core asp.net unit tests that depend on files - appsettings.json - fail in travis

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, nunit, asp.net-core, travis-ci

I've created an asp.net dot net core rtm (1.0.0-preview2-003121).

It uses ConfigurationBuilder to generate Configuration from appsettings.json:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

I've also tried '.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())`

Now my unit tests (in another project) i'm building an in-memory host:
I've tried:

```
_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
_client = _server.CreateClient();
```

And I've tried:

```
_server = new TestServer(
        new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>());
_client = _server.CreateClient();
```

My Travis.yml file is pretty standard:

```
 install:
# Install .net using linux CLI commands
  - sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet/ trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
  - sudo apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get -qq install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121
  - sudo apt-get install dotnet-hostfxr-1.0.2

script:
  - dotnet restore
  - dotnet build src/Speakr.WebApp.Site
  - dotnet build tests/Speakr.WebApp.Site.Tests
  - dotnet test tests/Speakr.WebApp.Site.Tests -f netcoreapp1.0
```

Locally, all work and builds. On both Windows and Ubuntu.
On travis CI tho, I'm getting the following error:
`Error : Speakr.WebApp.Site.Tests.InMemoryTests.HomeControllerIndexShouldNotBeNull`

Has anyone seen this?
I've tried adding a project.json to the test project, include CopyToOutput on the main project and include CopytoOutput on the test project.

Nada! :(

Comment: On a side note: Technically this isn't a unit test but an integration test :P

Comment: Yes, however, these tests are more useful to me as the controller->service->client layer is really really simple and with nothing to test, but these tests allow you to test the pipeline. So I've been "tending" to call them "my" unit tests but you are absolutely correct :)

Answer (score 3):

MVC's own functional/integration tests are a good example of how you can do this.

**MvcTestFixture**: (Notice the 'contentRoot' is calculated)
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1.0.0/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FunctionalTests/MvcTestFixture.cs

**Example of how it's used in a test**:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1.0.0/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FunctionalTests/BasicTests.cs

**Website or App against which the above test verifies**:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/1.0.0/test/WebSites/BasicWebSite

Comment: Hi, started peaking at this solution yesterday and this may hold the answer.

Comment: @jplebre Have you ever find the resolution for this issue? Please provide your answer I am struggling with the same issue.

Comment: @LP13 still no luck. The answer above should do it but it's way to over complicated. The .net docs suggest we should be able to do integration tests without that boilerplate. Still trying to get that working but really cannot spend too much time on it :(

Comment: @LP13 `"buildOptions": { "copyToOutput": [ "appsettings.json" ] }` will solve this. see my answer

Answer (score 3):

You should add

`"buildOptions": { "copyToOutput": [ "appsettings.json" ] }`

to your integration test project project.json,
then `.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)` will work, since when running the tests - appsettings.json will be at \test\IntegrationTestsProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1 - where the startup look for it.

Comment: I think this is the best solution.
In newer versions (without project.json) this boilds down to right click the file and set it to "copy to output"

Answer (score 1):

After a series of attempts, I found a possible solution. Since I need database initiation, I derived the main `Startup`. Several virtual functions inside the `TestStartup` are used to initiate the database. Then I make the `Configuration` inside the main `Startup` class protected settable. Finally:

```
public TestStartup(IHostingEnvironment env) : base(env)
{
    string basePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    if (!Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().EndsWith("IntegrationTest")) {
        basePath = Path.Combine(basePath, "MyProject.IntegrationTest");
    }

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.SetBasePath(basePath)
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Although the `basePath` fetching is a little ugly, this solution works for me.